# doing a look-up and writing a query to get the data from sql server 

Tags: java, sql-server, database, jdbc

While using Tomcat as the server and Derby as the database I did a look-up and executed the query like :

```
        Context initContext = new InitialContext();
        Context envContext = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:comp/env");
        DataSource ds = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/PollDatasource");
        Connection connection = ds.getConnection();
        // write the query that tells the current weight of actor
        String currentWeightQuery = "SELECT " + justPolled + ",total FROM pollresult";
        PreparedStatement currentWeight = connection.prepareStatement(currentWeightQuery);
        ResultSet cwSet = currentWeight.executeQuery();
```

Now I am using *Microsoft SQL Server 2005* and have to query the database from the java desktop application. What do I need to do query the sql server 2005 ? I have already loaded the sqlserver-jdbc driver and connected to the database but I don't know how to get the data from the database .

Comment: The code should be identical. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @JBNizet How do I define the datasource `(jdbc/PollDatasource)` ? Earlier I was defining in the context.xml of the web-app

Comment: You mean that the problem is that you're now trying to access the DB from a desktop application rather than a web app, and don't know how to define a DataSource, right? If so, use DriverManager directly to get 1 connection, or choose a connection ppol implementation (like C3P0) and read the instructions: http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#using_c3p0

Answer (score 0):

Now you need to iterate the ResultSet : [Retrieving and Modifying Values from Result Sets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html).

The ResultSet is actually a wrapper around a cursor in SQL server.
In this case you will probably get only one result.
You need to retrieve the value form the query using one of the getter methods of java.sql.ResultSet, depending on the expected datatype of your query result. As a method parameter you use either the name of the column as a string (""), or the sequence number of the column in the query, staring at 1. (one !)

Answer (score 0):

Try this after your last line of code above:

```
while (cwSet.next()) {
    String string = cwSet.getString(1); // instead of the 1 you can also use the name of the column as a String
    int i = cwSet.getInt("total"); //could also have used getInt(2)
    // etc...
}
```